# Ignore duplicates in results of a select statement based upon secondary column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Sorry if the title is a bit confusing, this is my first time posting.

Essentially, I have a table called roombooking, where a room has a room number(r_no), a bookingref (b_ref) and a checkin and checkout date (checkin and checkout respectively). Due to multiple different b_refs, an r_no appears in the table multiple times, with varying checkin and checkout dates.

What I want is to select all r_nos where checkin != "dateX", and for it to display only rooms where it, and any duplicates, do not contain "dateX" in the checkin column.

To provide an example data:

```
R_NO   B_REF  CHECKIN 
101      999  2019-09 
101      998  2019-08 
102      997  2019-07
```

What I essentially want to see when I run my SQL statement (where dateX = 2019-09) is for it to only select 102, as despite 101 (b_ref 998) having a different checkin date, it's duplicate has 2019-09 in the checkin column and so neither appear as a result.

For those wondering, my current SQL is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r_no 
from roombooking 
where checkin != '2019-09';
```

However (using the example data) this would return both 101 and 102 as results, which I don't want.

Hopefully, this is clear, and again I apologize if not, it's my first time posting.

Comment: You wrote "checkin and checkout date" - maybe you need to change search to `where '2019-09' between checkin and checkout` instead of just `<>` ? Because otherwise it's absolutely correct that you have non-unique results

Comment: Your sample data doesn't match the problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break it down into 2 conditions to apply as your filters -

1. `checkin` should not equal the specified date
2. `r_no` should not be the same `r_no` in rows where `checkin` is equal to the specified date

For example,

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT r_no FROM roombooking 
WHERE
   checkin != '2019-09' AND
   r_no NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT r_no FROM roombooking WHERE checkin = '2019-09')
```

There are multiple ways to achieve this, depending on your use-case and data size. A few options are

1. Use a sub-query to select duplicate rooms and eliminate them in your main query, as shown above
2. Use a CTE to select duplicate rooms and eliminate them in your main query by joining with the CTE
3. Self join on the same table to eliminate duplicate rooms

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your requirements, an easy way to go is

```
select distinct r_no from roombooking r1
where not exists (
    select * from roombooking r2
    where r1.r_no = r2.r_no
    and r2.checkin = '2019-09'
```